# Publish message from aws IoT mqtt when there is a change is s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, publish-subscribe, aws-iot

Currently I have AWS IoT which publishes message to the clients that are listening .
 But, Now I would want the AWS thing to publish the message to the clients whenever there is changes in S3 bucket .Similar to how lambda or SNS works . The trigger point should be modification in S3 bucket .

Any suggestions will be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Create an AWS Lambda function that is triggered by S3 new object events. Have the AWS Lambda function [publish to the topic using the AWS SDK](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iot-data.html#IoTDataPlane.Client.publish).

Comment: Thank you, But the Link is not clear on how to conect to AWS thing and how to publish topic in Lambda

Comment: There would be no IoT Thing needed. Not all IoT publishers/subscribers have to also be Things. You literally just have to call that one method I linked to in the SDK, giving it the topic name you want to publish to, and the payload to publish.